# NSPNGFileType - not found in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, xcode6

Today, I found something strange :

I wanted to write this code in swift :

```
    NSData *data = [myImage representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties: nil];
```

In swift it's look like this:

```
var data: NSData = imageToSave?.representationUsingType( NSPNGFileType ,
            properties: nil)
```

The problem is that the compiler say : " Use of unresolved identifier 'NSPNGFileType'". 
Does anyone have any idea why ?

Thanks, and sorry for my english !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the NSImage to tiff and then get the data using `.png` in Swift 5+.

To get the image data:

```swift
if let tiffRepresentation = icon.tiffRepresentation,
   let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffRepresentation) {
    let data = imageRep.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])
    
   // Use the data
}
```

If you want to save the image, you can write something like this:

For Mac apps, you may need to add "Capabilities" to save the file. Enable Read/Write for "Downloads Folder" in the App Sandbox.

```swift
let downloads = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser.appending(component: "Downloads")
let path = downloads.appending(components: "image.png")
if let tiffRepresentation = icon.tiffRepresentation,
   let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffRepresentation) {
    let data = imageRep.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])
    do {
        try data?.write(to: path, options: .atomic)
    } catch {
        print("Error saving: path\(path) error: \(error)")
    }
} else {
    print("Invalid image")
}
```

Comment: thanks. Strange thing. Before post question here, I've try to write NSBitmapImageFileType , but didin't work ;

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3 this has changed to simply `.PNG` or as the full version `NSBitmapImageFileType.PNG` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsbitmapimagefiletype)).